# How can an Arduino Mega 2560+Wifi Shield 2.0 (SeeedStudio) receive data from database in a XAMPP server on my PC?

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, shields, wifi, web-server

I'm trying to connect my Arduino Mega via Wifi to my XAMPP server. My main objective is get a value from my database and store it on a variable in Arduino code. With this new variable I'll be able to control the rest of the program... So I need your help. Can someone give me advice?

I already tried every thing that I found on the internet but it just doesn't work.

I think that the simple way is to send a GET request to the server and read its response... But for some reason I can't send a GET request through...

I tested it on the browser directly and the value shows up, so I think that the server side is all right.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "WiFly.h"
#include "HTTPClient.h"

#define SSID      "mySSID"
#define KEY       "myKEY"
#define AUTH      WIFLY_AUTH_WPA2_PSK
#define HTTP_GET_URL "http://192.168.1.80/xampp/training/send_data_db.php/?temp=0"

// Pins' connection
// Arduino       WiFly
//  2    <---->    TX
//  3    <---->    RX
SoftwareSerial uart(10, 11);
WiFly wifly(uart);
HTTPClient http;
char get;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("------- WIFLY HTTP --------");
  uart.begin(9600); // WiFly UART Baud Rate: 9600
  // Wait WiFly to init
  //  delay(3000);

  // check if WiFly is associated with AP(SSID)
  if (!wifly.isAssociated(SSID)) {
    while (!wifly.join(SSID, KEY, AUTH)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to join " SSID);
      Serial.println("Wait 0.1 second and try again...");
      delay(100);
    }
    wifly.save(); // save configuration,
  }
  Serial.println("\r\nTry to get url - " HTTP_GET_URL);
  Serial.println("------------------------------");
  while (http.get(HTTP_GET_URL, 10000) < 0) {
  }
  while (wifly.receive((uint8_t *)&get, 1, 1000) == 1) {
    Serial.print(get);
  }
  if (wifly.commandMode()) {
    Serial.println("\r\n\r\nEnter command mode. Send \"exit\"(with \\r) to exit command mode");
  }
}

void loop() {
  int c;
  while (wifly.available()) {
    c = wifly.read();
    if (c > 0) {
      Serial.write((char)c);
    }
  }
  while (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c >= 0) {
      wifly.write((char)c);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<? php
include("./connection/database_connect.php");
include("./top_table.php");

if ((isset($_SESSION["ID"])) AND (isset($_GET["temp"]))) {
  $id = $_SESSION["ID"];
  $sql = "SELECT temp FROM perfil, client WHERE perfil.ID ='$id'";
  $consult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
  $result = mysqli_num_rows($consult);
  if (($result == 1)) {
    $person_data = mysqli_fetch_array($consult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $temp = $person_data["temp"];
    header("HTTP/1.1" . " " . 200 . "OK");
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Length: 1112");
    header("Connection: close");
    header("/r/n");
    echo $temp;
  } else {
    //se user dosen't exist on data base
    header("Location: http://192.168.1.80/xampp/training/login.php");
    exit;
  }
} else {
  header("Location: http://192.168.1.80/xampp/training/login.php");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Step 1: confirm if the request is reaching the Apache server.

Comment: Sorry the delay but I just saw it now...

Yes the request is reaching the server. I tried with a simpler code just to be sure and the server sends a response, but not what I want.
It seems that the $_GET['temp'] is not set...

Comment: `php/?temp` - That looks "iffy" to me.  Should that `/` be in there?

Comment: I think so, just a while ago I spoted an error in that line I had "php/?$temp"  in there and solved part of my problem. It seems like the problem is that the $_SESSION can't be reached. And besides that my web page on the browser dosen't react

Comment: `$_SESSION` either needs cookies or a `PHPSESSID=....` parameter, neither of which you will likely have.

Comment: hum... that might be an issue, I'm only logging in an user in my browser and start the session in "include('./top_table.php'), maybe it isn't enough.
I thought that with the user logged in I could user his `$_SESSION` but it seems not...
Does `PHPSESSID` changes ever new session? if yes i don't think i can use it in Arduino code as a variable. 
what should i do? register arduino along with the info of the person/house? With that i might be able to acess the person ID and reach out "temp"

Comment: The PHPSESSID is a unique key that identifies the session.  It is allocated by PHP when the session is opened and must be provided back to PHP with every request to be able to access the session.  What you could do is perform a 2-stage login action, where you first go to a "login" page which returns your session ID, and then you make your normal (and all subsequent) request(s) including the session ID.

Comment: Filipe I need your help. Can you help me out from this! I need to store voltage sensor data from arduino mega using shield in local server. Please contact me at sjisylhet.partha@outlook.com
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should forget about the $_SESSION["ID"]; on PHP side, because you are working stateless without any session!
You should give a parameter for identifying your variable from arduino to php script - is this the temp=0? If so you need to exchange

```
$sql="SELECT temp FROM perfil, client WHERE perfil.ID ='$id'";
```

with

```
$sql="SELECT temp FROM perfil, client WHERE perfil.ID =" . $_GET["temp"];
```

assuming that perfil.id is only an integer - if it is a string, then add "'".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right!

Meanwhile i finished this project.

The problem was with the Wi-Fi shield that I was using. The Http request wasn't in a right format.